# Access function to return user's name, not username

Tags: windows, ms-access

Is there a function I can use to return the current users name to a textbox, rather than their username - so Joe Bloggs, not jbloggs?

Comment: Thats the username, not the user's name...

Comment: d'oh, my apologies, one sec...

Comment: If you have Active Directory set up, there's a post by Andrey Artemyev [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/accessdev/thread/39b12404-7dc1-4b37-b7e6-7c2f6bd545fe) that worked for me.

Comment: Excellent - the code there worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have Active Directory set up, you can use the following code, taken from [Andrey Artemyev's answer here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/accessdev/thread/39b12404-7dc1-4b37-b7e6-7c2f6bd545fe):

```
Public Function ADtest() As String
  Dim ADSI As Object, UN As Object
  Set ADSI = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
  Set UN = GetObject("LDAP://" & ADSI.UserName)
  ADtest = UN.FirstName
  ADtest = ADtest & " " & UN.LastName
  Set UN = Nothing
  Set ADSI = Nothing
End Function
```

<sub>(Adding answer here for better visibility, made Community Wiki since it's not really my answer, and I don't want the credit)</sub>

Comment: I'm keeping this as a favourite, I had no idea, great find : )